# Retrieve dynamic subdocuments key

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have this mongo documents

```
{
    "name": "aaa",
    "Time": "Now",
    "_id": "656i9gfk543klffx",
    "lastReadings": {
        "7-Temperature": {
            "_t": "NumberReading",
            "timestamp": "2017-02-13T12:51:50.000+0000",
            "unit": "C",
            "typeCode": 7,
            "name": "Temperature",
            "numberValue": 11.271406207825713
        },
        "30-DISCONNECT": {
            "_t": "NumberReading",
            "internalTimestamp": "2017-06-02T19:16:33.050+0000",
            "timestamp": "2017-06-02T19:16:27.147+0000",
            "unit": "",
            "typeCode": 30,
            "name": "DISCONNECT",
            "numberValue": 1
        }
    }
},
{
    "name": "aaa",
    "Time": "Now",
    "_id": "gtrg565opgf0",
    "lastReadings": {
        "7-Temperature": {
            "_t": "NumberReading",
            "timestamp": "2017-02-13T12:51:50.000+0000",
            "unit": "C",
            "typeCode": 7,
            "name": "Temperature",
            "numberValue": 46
        },
        "25-Water": {
            "_t": "NumberReading",
            "internalTimestamp": "2017-06-02T19:16:33.050+0000",
            "timestamp": "2017-06-02T19:16:27.147+0000",
            "unit": "",
            "typeCode": 25,
            "name": "Water",
            "numberValue": 1
        }
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to get distinct field keys from the "lastReadings" object where the "name" field equals to "aaa".
So the result I expect will be :

```
["7-Temperature", "30-DISCONNECT","25-Water"]
```

The subobjects keys inside "lastReadings" are dynamic and I can't know their names and how many fileds will be inside "lastReadings".

What aggregation query can I make to achieve this results?

I already got to this query:

```
{$match: {"name":"aaa"}},
{ $group: { _id: "name", mergedEvents: { $mergeObjects: "$lastReadings" } } }
```

But it's seems to run slow when I have lot of documents (will index on "lastReadings" improve performance?) and it returns the whole object which is not necessary.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, we can do this with the following pipeline:

```
[
   {
      "$group":{
         "_id":null,
         "lastReadings":{
            "$push":{
               "$map":{
                  "input":{
                     "$objectToArray":"$lastReadings"
                  },
                  "in":"$$this.k"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "$project":{
         "mergeEvent":{
            "$reduce":{
               "input":"$lastReadings",
               "initialValue":[

               ],
               "in":{
                  "$setUnion":{
                     "$concatArrays":[
                        "$$this",
                        "$$value"
                     ]
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
]
```

However I would suggest you review your schema design and remove the dynamic fields' name.

The "lastReadings" field could look like this:

```
{
   "lastReadings":[
      {
         "parameter":"7-Temperature",
         "value":{
            "_t":"NumberReading",
            "timestamp":"2017-02-13T12:51:50.000+0000",
            "unit":"C",
            "typeCode":7,
            "name":"Temperature",
            "numberValue":11.271406207825713
         }
      },
      {
         "parameter":"30-DISCONNECT",
         "value":{
            "_t":"NumberReading",
            "internalTimestamp":"2017-06-02T19:16:33.050+0000",
            "timestamp":"2017-06-02T19:16:27.147+0000",
            "unit":"",
            "typeCode":30,
            "name":"DISCONNECT",
            "numberValue":1
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

With such schema, you can retrieve distinct values using the `.disctinct` method and the *dot notation*

```
db.collection.distinct("lastReadings.parameter")
```